# How to add Javascript ad in my Android application

Tags: javascript, android, webview, ads

**I want to show a Javascipt ad* on top of my Android application.** Please help me with sample code. No help found on internet. Similar type of question asked in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fwc=1#!topic/android-developers/0dbOPwjQhhc) too.

*Javascript Ad example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">< 
window.googleAfmcRequest = { 
  client: 'ca-mb-pub-7387556283738751', 
  ad_type: 'text_image', 
  output: 'html', 
  channel: '', 
  format: '320x50_mb', 
  oe: 'utf8', 
  color_border: '336699', 
  color_bg: 'FFFFFF', 
  color_link: '0000FF', 
  color_text: '000000', 
  color_url: '008000', 
}; 
></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_afmc_ads.js 
(this 
link goes outside odesk.com)"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example on how to load a static page into a WebView: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/

... then as in the example, demo.html, you can call your JavaScript:

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/assets/demo.html